# How can I connect IPFS with infura when uploading data?

Tags: infura, polygon

I'm creating an NFT marketplace using hardhat, solidity & Next js, I have a form from where I enter some specific information about the NFT, then by clicking on the button "Create Digital Asset" The function ***"createMarket"*** should run to create an NFT and list it on the marketplace. When I clicked on the button to run the function ***"createMarket"***, I run into an error in these 2 lines of code saying that data in undefined!

```
const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}. 
const data = JSON.stringify({
            name, description, image: fileUrl
          });
```

I don't know how to solve it, I've tried to debug but everything seems right

What do you think ?

Btw I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKJBEEXUha0&t=6399s.

***This is my Create-items component:***

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from "ipfs-http-client";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'


const client = ipfsHttpClient('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0');

// import address
import {nftaddress, nftmarketaddress} from "../config";
 console.log(nftaddress, nftmarketaddress);
// import JSon files
import NFT from "../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json"
import Market from "../artifacts/contracts/Market.sol/NFTMarket.json";

export default function CreateItems() {

    const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState(null);
    console.log(fileUrl);
    const [formInput, updateFormInput] = useState({ price: '', name: '', description: '' });
    console.log(formInput);
    // create a reference to useRouter
    const router = useRouter();


    /* function to create and update the URL file */
    async function onChange(e) {
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        console.log(file)
        try {
          const added = await client.add(
            file,
            {
              progress: (prog) => console.log(`received: ${prog}`)
            }
          )
          ***const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`***
          setFileUrl(url)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error uploading file: ', error)
        }  
      }
   

    /* Function to create an items and save it to IPFS*/
      async function createMarket() {
          const { name, description, price } = formInput;
          if(!name || !description ||!price || fileUrl) return
          
          // Js object to data 
          const data = JSON.stringify({
            name, description, image: fileUrl
          });
          console.log(data);

          try {
            const added = await client.add(data)
            const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`
            /* after file is uploaded to IPFS, pass the URL to save it on Polygon */
            createSale(url)
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file: ', error)
          }  
        }

       /*Function for listing Items for sale */
      async function createSale(url) {
        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
        console.log(web3Modal);
        const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)    
        const signer = provider.getSigner()

          /* create or mint the NFT */
          let contract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, signer)
          let transaction = await contract.createToken(url)
          let tx = await transaction.wait()
          let event = tx.events[0]
          let value = event.args[2]
          let tokenId = value.toNumber()

          // parse what amount of ether that the user will enter in the input to Wei
          const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formInput.price, 'ether');
          
          
          /* List the items on sale on the marketplace */ 

          contract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, signer)
          let listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice()
          listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()

          transaction = await contract.createMarketItem(nftaddress, tokenId, price, {value: listingPrice});
          await transaction.wait();
          // push the user to the Home page
          router.push("/")

      }
    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center">

            <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12">
                <input
                  placeholder="Asset Name"
                  className="mt-8 border rounded p-4"
                  onChange={(e)=> updateFormInput({...formInput, name: e.target.value})}
                />

                <textarea
                  placeholder="Asset Description"
                  className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
                  onChange={(e)=> updateFormInput({...formInput, description: e.target.value})}
                />

                <input
                  placeholder="Asset Price in Eth"
                  className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
                  onChange={(e)=> updateFormInput({...formInput, price: e.target.value})}
                />

                <input
                  type="file"
                  name="asset"
                  className='my-4'
                  onChange={onChange}
                />

                {
                    fileUrl && (
                        <img className='rounded mt-4' width="350" src={fileUrl}/>
                    )
                }

                <button onClick={createMarket} className="font-bold mt-4 bg-pink-500 text-white rounded p-4 shadow-lg">
                    Create Digital Asset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Without more details it seems to be out of the scope for the site.

Comment: I edited my post Ismael showing more details :D

Comment: From the description it seems `client.add()` is failing. If that's the case I'd check if the ipfs url is still valid, of if you are sending the correct data.

Comment: How to check if it is valid or not?

Comment: Login into infura and check if it is enabled there? Read ipfsHttpClient documentation. etc.